# Pylucene installation on windows

Tags: python, installation, lucene, environment-variables, pylucene

I changed the Java JDK version to version 8, redefined the environment variables, reinstalled the JCC module successfully and changed the Makefile to have:

```
JAVA_HOME = C:/PROGRA~1/Java/jdk1.8.0_231
```

And now when I hit 'make' this error occurred:

```
While loading org/apache/pylucene/util/PythonComparable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jcc-3.7-py3.7-win-amd64.egg\jcc\__main__.py", line 107, in <module>
    cpp.jcc(sys.argv)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jcc-3.7-py3.7-win-amd64.egg\jcc\cpp.py", line 651, in jcc
    cls = findClass(className.replace('.', '/'))
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jcc-3.7-py3.7-win-amd64.egg\jcc\cpp.py", line 44, in findClass
    cls = _findClass(className)
jcc.cpp.JavaError: Java Error
make: *** [Makefile:386: compile] Error 1
```

What could be a possible solution?

Comment: A couple of thoughts: (1) PyLucene requires Java v8, according to [this page](https://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/). Looks like you are using v14. (2) You may already have seen [this guide](https://lxsay.com/archives/365) - but it mentions `jcc3` a few times in the comments/troubleshooting section.

Comment: @andrewjames I changed the Java SDK version to 8 and encountered a different error. I am posting an answer with it right now.

Comment: You should edit your current question to include this new information, and then delete your answer. (Or you can delete both the question and answer, and ask a new question.)

Comment: @andrewjames Just deleted the answer and changed the question, thanks.

Comment: can you invoke jcc and see if it gives any error. Type 'python -m jcc' in cmd.